# "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Illegal arguments: undefined, string"

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I was trying to follow up this "Build A Node.js API Authentication With JWT Tutorial" on YouTube. For some reason  the post request of `/register`, is giving me this error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Illegal arguments: undefined, string.

Below you can find the code:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const User = require('../user');
const {resigerValidate} = require('../validation');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')

router.post('/register', async (req, res)=>{
    // doing validation from validation.js
    const {error} = resigerValidate(req.body);
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
    if (error) {
        return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
    }
    // checks if the email already exists in the database (partially working)
    const emailExists = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email});
    if (emailExists){
        return res.status(400).send('This email already exists in the database !!!');
    } 
    // user creation
    const user = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: hashedPassword
    });
    try{
        const savedUser = await user.save();
        res.send(savedUser);
    }catch(err){
        res.status(400).send(err);
    }
      
});



module.exports = router;


// Error

(node:15748) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Illegal arguments: undefined, string
    at _async (C:\Users\Admin\JavaScript\jwt\jwt\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:214:46)
    at C:\Users\Admin\JavaScript\jwt\jwt\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:223:17
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.bcrypt.hash (C:\Users\Admin\JavaScript\jwt\jwt\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:222:20)
    at C:\Users\Admin\JavaScript\jwt\jwt\routes\auth.js:19:41
(node:15748) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:15748) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate 
the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: You should provide the full error stack. Which line throws this error? It's probably the `req.body.password` is `undefined`.

Comment: Yes, I just added the error

Answer (score 0):

According to your stack info `bcrypt.hash(..)` is rejected. Looks like you need to move this part of the code a little bit lower. Something like

```js
    const {error} = resigerValidate(req.body);
    // checks if the email already exists in the database (partially working)
    const emailExists = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email});
    if (emailExists){
        return res.status(400).send('This email already exists in the database !!!');
    } 
    try{
    // user creation
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
        if (error) {
            return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
        }
        const user = new User({
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: hashedPassword
        });
        const savedUser = await user.save();
        res.send(savedUser);
    }catch(err){
        res.status(400).send(err);
    }
```

Comment: I tried something similar but when I move that password part a little lower, for some reason the joi validation doesn't work.
When I send the post request it gives me a 400 error saying "name" is required

Comment: Check what you sent from the client to API.